# MSQL Create table with restricted values

Tags: mysql

How do i create table in MYSQL with column name Marks Decimal (3,2) which should be less than 100 while inserting the value and default value must be ZERO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make that column `decimal(4, 2)`: the highest value it can store is `99.99` - and use a `default` clause:

```
create table mytable (
    ...,
    marks decimal(4, 2) default 0

)
```

Comment: @RoyalSession Note that this strategy silently converts a value like 100 to 99.99, which might not align with user expectations.